# To generate create statement of a table as output in talend, given the table name as input in a csv file

Tags: salesforce, talend

I am trying to generate create statement of a table as output, if I give the table name as input in a csv file. I am trying to achieve this in talend.

*Note: The table is present in the metadata.*

E.g. If the table name is 'Account', so the csv file will contain the name 'Account' and the output of the talend job should produce the create statement of Account table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information about what you have tried so far, how your job does look like and what problems you ran into. Also, how does the schema look like? Always the same? If not, where do you store the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the table name from your input file (here Account), set a global variable with this value and reuse the global variable as the table name in the component configuration or SQL statement.

Hope this helps.
TRF